# Passing a spinner selected value to another value

Tags: android, json, spinner, android-spinner

Once a value is selected from the spinner, I am looking to have another list of values populate the spinner from the selection made. For example: When the user clicks the spinner the values "Home Team, Home Subs, Home Other" comes up. The user clicks one of these and then the players that are affiliated with that selection then populate the spinner. Below is code for the original spinners populated.

```
public class ExampleMain extends Activity {

        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        JSONArray str_login = null;
        public String kode;
        public String Team_Name;
        public String Home_team;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);  

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            String link_url = "http://10.0.2.2/NPD/P_name.php";
            JSONObject json = jParser.FunctionParser(link_url);
            Spinner d11 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.doubles11);
            Spinner d12 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.doubles12);
            Spinner d21 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.doubles21);
            Spinner d22 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.doubles22);
            Spinner d31 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.doubles31);
            Spinner d32 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.doubles32);


                try {
                        jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("team");
                        final String[] items = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);           
                        items[i]=jsonObject.getString("P_name");
                        }

           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, 
                   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);      
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
           d11.setAdapter(adapter);


           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
           d12.setAdapter(adapter);

           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                   this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
           d21.setAdapter(adapter);

           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                   this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
           d22.setAdapter(adapter);

           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                   this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
           d31.setAdapter(adapter);

           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                   this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
           d32.setAdapter(adapter);




                } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you achieved until now?

Comment: You must accept an answer. Don't be one of that guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html)

```
d11.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View view, int position,long arg3)
    {
         item = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }

     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
    // Do nothing.
    }
```

Now you will have your value and you can use that wherever you need to populate the other `Spinners`. Make `item` in this example a member variable so you can use it anywhere in this `Activity`. You will also need to add `implements OnItemSelectedListener` to your class definition

```
public class ExampleMain extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
```

Also, you are initializing `adapter` many times with the same values it looks like. Just initialize it once then set your `Adapters` on your `Spinners`

Comment: I am looking for the new data to populate the same spinner. Essentially, once the first value is clicked, that data is cleared and the players affiliated with the clicked variable now populate the spinner. Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, just change the adapter to use a different list when you an item is selected

Comment: Either change the adapter and call `setAdapter(yourNewAdapter)` or change the values in the list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the old `adapter`